# Why would data structures like queues and stacks be used if arrays are easier to use and more powerful?

Tags: java, data-structures, language-agnostic

This may be a silly question, but it's been bugging me for a while. Most programming languages have arrays (e.g. Java, C/C++, C#...ok Python has lists!) but in much of the literature I see, some data structures (such as stacks and queues) are treated as more basic as arrays. But since so many languages have such great support for arrays, why would anyone use a stack or queue? I realize that conceptually a data structure other than an array may better fit the model, but considering you may have to implement your own stack or queue it's a lot more work considering how fundamental arrays are.

One example I'm thinking of is from [these notes](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos423/lectures/01StableMatching-2x2.pdf) on the Gale Shapley 
algorithm `Maintain a list of free men (in a stack or queue).`
Wouldn't it be easier to just use an array and trust yourself to only look at the front/end of it?

I guess I'm asking, why would anyone bother using something like a stack or queue when most are implemented using arrays, and arrays are more powerful anyways?

Comment: Where does it say that stacks and queues are more basic than arrays? Not in your citation.

Comment: Desired behavior, encapsulation and DRY.

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons. First of all, it's helpful if your implementation more closely matches the algorithm. That is, if your algorithm uses a stack it's useful if you can say, for example, `stack.push(thing)` rather than writing:

```
if (stack_index >= stack_array.length)
{
    // have to extend the stack
    ....
}
stack_array[stack_index++] = thing
```

And you'd have to write that code *every place* you push something onto the stack. And you'd have to write multiple lines of code every time you wanted to pop from the stack.

I don't know about you, but I find it incredibly easy to make mistakes when I'm writing code like that.

Seems easier, much more clear, and way more reliable to encapsulate that functionality into a `Stack` object that you can then use as it's intended: with calls to `push` and `pop` methods.

Another benefit is that when you find yourself having to do a quick thread-safe stack, you can modify your `Stack` class to put locks around any code that changes the internal structure (i.e. the array), and any callers automatically have a thread-safe stack. If you were to address the array directly in your code, then you'd have to go to every place that you access the underlying array and add your lock statements. I'd give better than even odds that you'd make a mistake in there somewhere and then you'd have an interesting time tracking down that intermittent failure.

Arrays themselves aren't particularly powerful. They're *flexible*, but they have no smarts. We wrap behavior around arrays to limit what they can do so that we don't have to "trust ourselves" not to do stupid things, and also so that we can do the right things more easily. If I'm implementing an algorithm that uses a queue, then I'm going to be thinking in terms of a queue that has Enqueue and Dequeue operations rather than in terms of a linked list or an array that has head and tail indexes that I have to manage, etc.

Finally, if you write a Stack or Queue or similar data structure implementation, test it and prove it correct, you can use it over and over again in multiple projects without ever having to look at the code again. *It just works.* That's opposed to rolling your own with an array so that you have to debug it not just in every project you use a stack in, but you have the potential of screwing up every single push or pop.

To sum up, we create data structures rather than use raw arrays:

1. Because it's easier to think in terms of data structure operations rather than the mechanics of working with an array.
2. Code re-use: write once, debug, and then use it in multiple projects.
3. Simplifies code (`stack.push(item)` rather than multiple lines of array indexing).
4. Reduces potential for error.
5. Easier for the next guy to come by and understand what you did. "Oh, he's pushing items onto a stack."

Answer (score 1):

Internally I'd say most of those classes are implemented with the help of arrays. But it would be tedious to use Arrays as Stacks or Queues. Arrays are fixed length things where you cannot insert stuff at arbitrary places. You would have to do much copying around of array elements, enlarging and shrinking the array or keep in mind what your head and tail positions are etc. The Stack and Queue classes do all this for you and you can just use the much more convenient push, pop, etc. methods.

Comment: Trees, linked lists... it's not just arrays.

Comment: @Kayaman but there are situations where those have useful properties: binary tree is easy to search, and linked list is easy to add and remove form (these are things that arrays can't do).

Comment: @Celeritas I know. I was referring to "most of those classes are implemented with arrays", when there are plenty of data structures that don't rely on arrays.

Comment: @Kayaman we talked about Stacks and Queues. But yes, there can be other implementations of course. We don't have to care, that's the good point. :-)

Comment: @Vampire I assumed his wording of "data structures *like* queues and stacks" didn't mean **only** queues and stacks. Besides, linked lists are great for both of those and trees can be used for priority queues. In fact looking at Java collections, you can see that arrays aren't used *that* much in the internal implementations. Naturally the `ArrayList`, `ArrayBlockingQueue` and others that make it obvious, `HashMap`'s internal hashtable is an array...

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are just one more type of data structure. They have specific use cases, just like any other.

All data structures have particular properties, e.g.

- fixed vs variable size;
- ordered vs unordered;
- allows duplicates vs prohibits duplicates
- covariant or not
- can contain primitives or not
- specific time complexity on insertion/removal/retrieval operations
- iteration order
- ...

Whether you choose to use an array or any other data structure depends upon what you are trying to do, and whether that data structure possesses the properties you require.

And it is better to have simple data structures which do one thing well, than to attempt to have an uber data structure which does everything.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the size of stacks and queues easier than the size from an array
thats is very difficult.
if you know how big your array should be, use an array. but if you don#t know it stacks and queues are the better choice.

Comment: I didn't think about it, but how is it that "you can change the size of stacks and queues easier than the size from an array" when they are implemented using arrays?

Comment: They are not necessarily implemented using arrays. But even if they are, you can just add an object and the internals of the class care about enlarging the data store. Basically your questions means "why use existing code if I can all do myself?". There are many libraries out there that you can use, but you can also do all that they do in your custom code. It just does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Admirable that you would trust yourself so much, but when you're creating a project with several other developers (or even by yourself), you can't rely on trust.

Different data structures make it more obvious what the code is doing, it prevents you from doing wrong things (no matter how much you trust yourself), they can provide performance, concurrency or content guarantees and dozens of other things that simple arrays can't do or just aren't the best fit for.

Why would you have pockets when backpacks are invented?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Vampire. Arrays provide instant access to any of it's elements if you have the index. Whereas stacks and queues give you the convenience of LIFO and FIFO orderings which allow you to implement many algorithms much easier. Also with the stacks and queues it's easier to add or remove elements since with array you have a limited memory at all times and your variables are in consecutive memory blocks you would have to move a lot of data and allocate/deallocate memory accordingly. Please check this [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-would-one-want-to-use-a-stack-queue-over-an-array) for further information.